# Why I can open Reddit in Chrome but not in Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, reddit, dns

Instead, I got this:

[image]

Basically, Firefox complains that Reddit has a certificate for firstmedia.com

firstmedia.com is my ISP. In Indonesia, ISP is required to block bad sites and Reddit is one of the site blocked.

They do so by poisoning DNS or something. By changing the DNS I usually can access Reddit.

However, for some reason, firefox still thinks that Reddit uses firsmedia.com's certificate.

Chrome doesn't.

Why?

And what should I do to be able to open Reddit in Firefox?

Answer (score 1):

Well, as you mentioned - DNS. Chrome uses its own DNS `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` while Firefox relies on default (ISP) DNS. You should be able to resolve your issue by applying global DNS on your PC and also you should go for such DNS which is secured enough to not be read by your ISP (like [**https://1.1.1.1/dns/**](https://1.1.1.1/dns/))

Comment: I already replace the DNS with 1.1.1.1 using DNS jumper

Comment: It seems that firefox "cache" those certificates. How do I flush the certificates?